# Maintain font styling (overriding font at cursor placement) for a session

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, text-editing, microsoft-onenote

I am creating a document iteratively, adding a new "layer" of notes from one editing session to the next. The process to create the final version might take several passes/sessions/iterations to complete; all changes are additive.

I would like to distinguish the notes I type in a text editor (preferably Microsoft Word or OneNote) from one session to another, such that I can tell which notes I made on the first, second, third, etc. iterations.

My initial hope is that Word has a setting that would allow a text color to persist no matter where I click in the text, and no matter what the fonts/styles/colors of the surrounding text are. I want to bring a static formatting with my cursor wherever it starts typing.

It seems like there would be something like a "notes mode" that a user can toggle on and off, with a definable font styling.  Is this a thing?? Macro, plug-in, etc.?

Comment: What if you use track changes?  You could change the settings for colours to By Author, and then for each session, change your username in Word to add session number at end eg ABC1 for your edits on first session, ABC2 for your edits in second session.  That way each session would be a different author and all edits for that session would be one particular colour, and for another session would be a different colour again.

Comment: Interesting idea, but from what I can tell, changing usernames in Word doesn't work like that. The section heading for entering a new username is titled "Personalize your copy of Microsoft Office" and appears to allow only one username at a time (not maintaining "separate" usernames at a time). So it seems that would be the same as changing my user's default font every time I started a new session, since it can't "remember" Session1User's default font and Session2User's, but only MyUser's default font. Thoughts?

Comment: I have done what Tanya described (with track changes).  I did it a few years ago — I believe that it was with Word 2007 or earlier — and I’ve just done it again with Word 2013. But it seems not to work if you are logged in to a Microsoft account.